# Date difference in days in ruby and javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Ruby and javascript calculate date differences differently.

Ruby:

```
Date.today - Date.new(2000, 01, 01)
# => (5329/1)
```

JavaScript:

```
(new Date() - new Date(2000,1,1))/86400000
5298.566723310185
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Javascript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) object starts month at 0.

Comment: omg, I'm an idiot, make it an answer pls, i will accept

Comment: If I tell you how many times I had problem with that, dude.. haha

Comment: from the downvotes looks like it's just 2 of us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) object starts counting month at 0. So:

```
(new Date() - new Date(2000,1,1))/86400000
```

Should be:

```
(new Date() - new Date(2000,0,1))/86400000
```